# JSON.Parse causes error in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm having some problems with JSON.Parse in my code and I cant find the reason of this I have a function which call two ajax functions, one on the start and another on the success function . Its working fine but when I'm try to parse the second one response the code breaks without giving any error  and the real mystery is `JSON.parse(object);` dosent give any problem but when I use a variable to store the result like this `var list =JSON.parse(object);` my code broke and I dont what is the reason behind this  my current code is given below

```
function getData()
{
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "MyPage.aspx/GetData",
                data: JSON.stringify({ data: data})
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    var result = JSON.parse(response.d);
                    var temp = 0;
                    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

                        if (result[i].data > 1) {
                            var subList = JSON.parsegetFullData (result[i].id));
                        }

                }
            });
}
     function getFullData (id) {
            var sublist;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "MyPage.aspx/GetData2",
                data: JSON.stringify({ id: id }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    return response.d;
                }
            });

        }
```

any thought will help a lot

Comment: Are you sure `response.d` is a string containing JSON? Btw, `return response.d;` from the callback won't have any effect.

Comment: Then it wouldn't throw an error. Please post the response.

Comment: @FelixKling thats what I said its not throwing any error

Comment: This is the response "[{"id":0,"LastName":test0,"FirstName":test0,"Age":10,"DOB":"1/23/2013"},{{"id":1,"LastName":test1,"FirstName":test1,"Age":11,"DOB":"2/23/2013"}},{{"id":2,"LastName":test2,"FirstName":test2,"Age":12,"DOB":"3/23/2013"}},{{"id":3,"LastName":test3,"FirstName":test3,"Age":13,"DOB":"4/23/2013"}}]"

Comment: Ok, those `{{` are not valid. If any, this is an array of objects, not an object with property `d`. And in your title you are saying  `JSON.Parse causes error in javascript`.

Comment: @FelixKling sorry The extra } is my typing error I've to change the data

Comment: "[{"id":0,"LastName":test0,"FirstName":test0,"Age":10,"DOB":"1/23/2013"},{"id":1,"LastName":test1,"FirstName":test1,"Age":11,"DOB":"2/23/2013"},{"id":2,"LastName":test2,"FirstName":test2,"Age":12,"DOB":"3/23/2013"},{"id":3,"LastName":test3,"FirstName":test3,"Age":13,"DOB":"1/23/2013"}]"

Comment: The above is the actual response format I got from The server

Comment: Ok, so `response` will be an array of objects. And arrays don't have a property `d`. Just do `result = response;` or rename the function parameter. I wonder why thought you have to use `response.d`?

Comment: @FelixKling its not working when i return the the value its shows undefined

Comment: You cannot return the value from the callback function. See [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `$.ajax` with `dataType:"json"`, the response is already parsed for you. And there doesn't seem to be a reason to try to parse `response.d`.

Simply use

```
$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "MyPage.aspx/GetData",
           data: JSON.stringify({ data: data})
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType: "json",
           success: function (results) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    console.log(results[i].id, results[i].LastName);
```

Comment: I know that the server response is a serialized collection and when I inspect response.d  its a large string

Comment: Is it a JSON string ? Why would you put JSON into JSON ?

Comment: I want it as json object not string and also the method  JSON.parse(data) works perfectly in the first function

Comment: @Optimus:  [There is no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: Typically, an object, even deeply structured, is serialized into a sole JSON string. You only have to parse this string to get the whole structure, you don't have to parse the internal properties.

Comment: @Optimus I've seen your JSON in comment, there is no reason to parse the properties. Directly use the response which is an array. I've added an example of use of the properties (the `console.log`).

Comment: its not working when i return the the value its shows undefined